error in connecting to local SSH server using vscode ase: error: TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
I'm pretty new to this field fyi...
so at school I'm connected to a local ssh server(tcsh shell) where we run the dft calculations.
I normally used mobaxterm to connect to the server as other people and had no trouble running ase gui.
when I go see the environment values, out of many env variables out there I can see
set DISPLAY=localhost:0.0
when I echo $DISPLAY i get localhost:0.0
I recently wanted to use vscode to connect to the same server.
I installed Remote-SSH and set the config setting to be
HOST []
   HOSTNAME [ssh IP]
   USER [myid]
   Port 22
   ForwardX11 yes
   ForwardX11Trusted yes

Then, I set the Xming on my windows pc.
and have successfully connected to the ssh using vscode. However, when I try to use ase gui in the terminal or in the ipynb, I was keep getting
File "/mifs/pdm9600/apps/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2023, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

It works fine when using mobaxterm. I don't know what I should do to make it work on vscode.. thanks in advance for the help
So when setting Xming, I went into Xlaunch,
set multiple windows, Display number 0, checked the 'Start no client', checked 'No Access Control' and finished the setting. Xming Server:0.0 is running visible on the right bottom of my screen.
I went into set the env. var.. From top one (where it says User variable', I created new variable called DISPLAY and set the value to be localhost:0.0
I'm troubled as to understand why it is working on mobaxterm just fine, but not on vscode.. :(
